# How to support UTF8 characters for email addresses in Microsoft Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-server

In our web application we are using Microsoft exchange to forward emails. I don't know if it possible. Can we have email addresses with UTF8 characters like european, Spannish characters for email address. For example :

εζηθRaηθ@domainname.com (whateverthe domain we have).

In more brief, can we create email address with UTF8 characters. I have read somewhere on internet that Messages in Microsoft exchange can be utf-8 supported(in this case we have to change character encoding), But there was no clarification related to the email addresses.

Currently, i am not able to generate email addresses in Microsoft exchange. Attaching the screenshot of the same. Please see below :

[image]

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

**Note : Using Microsoft exchange 2013**

Comment: I think that's forbidden. Everything in front of the @ must be plain ASCII. This is unrelated to Exchange but the email RFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#page-42

> Systems MUST NOT define mailboxes in such a way as to require the
> use    in SMTP of non-ASCII characters (octets with the high order bit
> set    to one) or ASCII "control characters" (decimal value 0-31 and
> 127).    These characters MUST NOT be used in MAIL or RCPT commands or
> other    commands that require mailbox names.

It seems Exchange and Office 365 atleast do not support UTF-8 characters in the From/To fields

UTF-8 is supported only in the content of the body

Refer http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/220395.aspx

Comment: The Office 365 part of this answer is out-of-date. They now support `SMTPUTF8`. Telnet to the MX record on port 25 for (e.g.) outlook.com and ask the server for `ehlo sj`.